# Realteck RTL8821AE under Kubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I've just bought a Gigabyte Brix pro to make a small portable NAS
I've installed  Kubuntu 14.10 on it

Unfortunately I've got some trouble with wifi.
It use a Realteck RTL8821AE chip. 
When I look at the log, the wifi driver is switching between the 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz channel all time.

I was able to connect to a 2.4Ghz channel once, but the connection failed after a while, it recognize my 5Ghz channel (moxWifi 5 Ghz) once, never connect, and after a while, got some trouble with the space in the name - so I've changed it (moxWifi5Ghz) with no improvement.

For the moment I'm blocked

Tks for your help

Guillaume

PS : I also have some trouble with the Bluetooth, able to connect the Mouse but no Keyboard ...

Comment: This question should be asked at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). Stack Overflow is about programming problems.

Comment: Will do that Tks for advise